Connecting a dataframe and another 1d dataframe isn't a problem, but when using the [...] operator it yields different results
I have an original dataframe og_df and a sublist dataframe, which is a part of the og_df. I want to create a new dataframe new_df which contains the elements of og_df and every n following elements in the og_df.
Example:
og_df = pd.DataFrame({'column': range(20)})
sub_df = pd.DataFrame({'column': [ 1, 2, 10 ]})
n = 3  
new_df = pd.DataFrame({'column':[]})

for index in sub_df.index:
    new_df = pd.concat([new_frame, og_df.iloc[index:index + n]])
print(new_df)

>>>    column
    0    1
    1    2
    2    3
    1    2
    2    3
    3    4
    11   10
    12   11
    13   12

This worked the way I wanted and gives the desired result. However, when og_df has multiple columns and I use the [..] operator, or if it has one column and I use the [..] operator it does behave like this:
for index in sub_df.index:
    new_df = pd.concat([new_frame, og_df['column'].iloc[index:index + n]])
print(new_df)

>>>    column     0
1      NaN   1.0
2      NaN   2.0
3      NaN   3.0
2      NaN   2.0
3      NaN   3.0
4      NaN   4.0
10     NaN  10.0
11     NaN  11.0
12     NaN  12.0


How can I make it behave like desired? I aim to select just one column from a multicolumn og_df and that's the reason i'm using the [..] operator.

The issue you're facing is that you're using a single slice [] instead of double slice [[]].
If you update your loop the code works:
new_df = pd.DataFrame({'column':[]})
for index in sub_df.index:
    new_df = pd.concat([new_df, og_df[['column']].iloc[index:index + n]])
print(new_df)


Output:
   column
0     0.0
1     1.0
2     2.0
1     1.0
2     2.0
3     3.0
2     2.0
3     3.0
4     4.0


This happens because a single slice gives a series:
type(og_df['column']), type(og_df[['column']])

(pandas.core.series.Series, pandas.core.frame.DataFrame)


so generally speaking if I want to access values in a column of a datafram I should use the double slice? What if I want to access a value at position x in a column, would that be just df[['column']][[x]] ?

it depends if you need a series or a dataframe, though for most case it will be treated equivalently (this question being an exception).
If you want to access a specific position, I recommend using iloc or loc (see guide )

IIUC, don't use concat in a loop, this is highly inefficient (quadratic behavior). Instead, craft an indexer with numpy and use a single iloc:
idx = np.where(og_df['column'].isin(sub_df['column']))[0]
# array([ 1,  2, 10])
idx2 = (idx[:,None]+np.arange(n)).ravel()
# array([ 1,  2,  3,  2,  3,  4, 10, 11, 12])
out = og_df[['column']].iloc[idx2[idx2<len(og_df)]]

Output:
    column
1        1
2        2
3        3
2        2
3        3
4        4
10      10
11      11
12      12


thank you for the improvement thats terrific. I only changed ['column'] to 0 when using iloc because it takes numerical values

@100xln2 you're welcome. Pandas rule #1 never use iterrows, concat in a loop or apply with axis=1, unless you are absolutely sure there is no alternative ;)

The reason you're getting NaN values is that  new_df empty DataFrame pd.DataFrame({'column': []}). new_df initially has no rows or data, its column will be considered as having dtype object, and the concatenation operation will result in columns with missing values NaN for those rows in for index in sub_df.index:
. Instead of that you can initialize your new_df 2 different ways.
First one is :
new_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=og_df.columns) 

Second one is:
new_df = pd.DataFrame() 

So, final example code
import pandas as pd

og_df = pd.DataFrame({'column1': range(20), 'column2': range(20, 40)})
sub_df = pd.DataFrame({'column': [1, 2, 10]})
n = 3
new_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=og_df.columns) 

for index in sub_df.index:
    new_df = pd.concat([new_df, og_df.iloc[index:index + n]])

print(new_df)

